# Is there any formula for arrangement with limited repetitions?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm aware of the following formula for **arrangement with repetition**:

$$AR_{n,k}=n^k$$

But it implies that every single element can be repeated. I want a formula to use when **some of the elements have limited copies of themselves**. For example:

> Q: How many three-letter anagrams can be produced from the word "combination"?

If the word was "formula" I could just do $A_{7,3}=\frac{7!}{(7-3)!}=210$, because every letter only appears once. And if the anagram had the same length as "combination", I could do $P^{2,2,2}_{12}=\frac{P_{12}}{P_2\,P_2\,P_2}=\frac{12!}{(2!)^3}=59875200$.

All in all, I was wondering if there was a formula similar to **permutation with repetition** but for **arrangement**.

Comment: You do not need a general formula; this problem is small enough to solve in a couple cases. There are only three repeated letters in combination, and they each appear twice. So, for each of those repeated letters, you can count the number the number of words using both of those letters. With those out of the way, every other word uses distinct letters, which you know how to count.